# How to implement Single Sign On with Keycloak and Ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, single-sign-on, ejabberd, keycloak

I have an application authenticated using keycloak oauth2. Here the user gets a token for further interactions. Now I am implementing a chat feature using XMPP protocol ejabberd server. User needs jid and password to connect and login to ejabberd server. How can we make these a single sign on ?

Comment: The most sane approach would be to create custom SASL mechanism, that would take token from the client during XMPP SASL negotiation and verify that token agains keycloak.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that XMPP does not implement single-sign-on.
There has been a XEP but it has been deferred. https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0101.html

That means the only 'good' possibility is, to keep the tcpclient/xmppclient running forever, while reusing its connection whenever you start your application.